# fail to store date of birth data to database

Tags: php

i have tried to store register data to database and it works perfectly without date of birth. when i put date of birth, it never store to the database. what would be the problem?

here is the sample code

```
include('config.php');
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
                $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
                $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                $dob = $_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' . $_POST['day'];
                mysql_real_escape_string($dob);
                $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
                $mobilenumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobilenumber']);
                $postalcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postalcode']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){
            if(empty($fname)){
                echo '';
            }else{
            $success=("INSERT INTO customer (FName, LName, DoB, Email, Password, MobileNum, PostalCode) 
            VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$dob', '$email', '$password', '$mobilenumber','$postalcode')");
            mysql_query($success);
            Header("Location: ?");
            }
            }
```

Comment: what error you are getting? and what is DATATYPE of DOB field?

Comment: check your database field type is "date"

Comment: well, it doesnt appear any error, but it doesnt added to database

Comment: try using `mysql_query($success) or die (mysql_error());` this will at least give you an error message

Comment: 1. You use deprecated `mysql` extension. 2. You hide mysql errors (use `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: i've tried to use the error but it doesnt appear anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
$dob = $_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' . $_POST['day'];
```

TO

```
$dob = $_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' . $_POST['day'];
$dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob));
```

Hope it help.